# Find the image of the vector v under the mapping f

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This question comes from *Ordinary Differential Equations, Arnold, P67*, and it asks

"Suppose v is a positive unit vector of the line attached at the point a and let $f(x) = x^2$. Find $f_{*a}v$."

I tried the following:
\begin{align*}
f_{*a}v &= \frac{d}{dt} \Big|_{t = 0} f(\phi(t)) \\
&= \frac{df(\phi(t))}{dt} \Big|_{t = 0} \cdot \frac{\phi(t)}{dt} \Big|_{t = 0} \\
&= 2a \Big|_{t = 0} \cdot v \\
&= 2at
\end{align*}
It is indeed the final answer but I don't know how 
$\frac{df(\phi(t))}{dt} \Big|_{t = 0} = 2a \Big|_{t = 0}$
or I did it wrong.

Here is the definition in the book:

The *Image of the vector v under the mapping f* is the velocity vector with which the moving point $f(\phi(t))$ leaves the point $f(x)$ when the moving point $\phi(t)$ leaves the point $x$ with velocity $v$:
$$
f_{*x} v = \frac{d}{dt} \Big|_{t = 0} f(\phi(t)), \quad \text{where } \phi(0) = x, \quad \frac{d}{dt} \Big|_{t = 0} \phi(t) = v
$$

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you know what $\phi(t)$ is(both its definition and why it's defined like that)? Without the definition, the third step is not clear at all, an without knowing why it's defined like that, you will not know the significance of the quantity you are calculating!

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Yes, I don't really understand the definition, and that is one reason why I ask this question(attempting to learn from the example)

Comment: Ok, I will try to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See, the idea is that $f_{*a}$ is a linear transformation for each point $a$ on the curve. How does this work?

Recall that in multivariable calculus, the derivative of a function is a linear transformation : it takes a vector and returns the "infinitesimal change" of the function along that direction.

The better way of understanding things is that the derivative is the best linear approximation to a function at a point. So, if you have a function and a point, and you want to understand how the function behaves in a neighbourhood of this point, then you can use a "best" linear approximation of the function, which comes as a linear transformation.

For example, take $f(x) = x^2$. Here, the derivative is a "number", which does not sound like a linear transformation : but it is, for every number $a$ may be interpreted as the linear transformation $v \to av$(i.e. scaling) for any vector $v$.

---

Now, what is $\phi$? Note that $\phi$ is called a "moving point", but in truth it is a "parametrization". What does that mean?

Think of it this way : imagine you have a real number $x'$ close to $x$, and you want to find the value of the function at $x'$. For this, it would be nice if you had a "path" from $x$ to $x'$, which you could travel along .Think of $\phi$ as a path in that case, which starts from $x$ and goes to a point where you want to find the function value.

Now, that is why $\phi(0) = x$ : the path should start at $x$. But then, we also know that the "velocity" $v$ of the path is given : that is why we require $\frac{d \phi}{dt}\Big|_{t=0} = v$.

So what does this achieve? Well, this allows approximation when $x'$ lies in the direction $v$ from $x$. So, in  some sense, $\phi$ is the *straight line* starting from $x$ in the direction $v$! And the points we would like to approximate are points lying close to $x$ in this direction from $x$.

---

With that, the model requires $\phi(t) = x+tv$ for $t \in [0,\epsilon)$ with $\epsilon$ as small as required(It doesn't matter, we are taking the derivative at zero anyway) so that we have a straight line.

---

Now, the best linear approxmation of $f$ is to be rephrased in terms of the parametrizing variable $t$ as $\frac{d(\phi(t))}{dt}|_{t=0}$, where $t = 0$ is because $\phi(0) = x$. Now, using the chain rule,
$$
\frac{d f(\phi(t))}{dt} = \frac{d(f(\phi(t)))}{d\phi(t)} \frac{d\phi(t)}{dt}
$$

And therefore, now we use the formula which tells us that the first fraction is just the derivative of $x^2$ at $a$ which is $2a$. The second fraction is the derivative of $x + tv$ w.r.t $t$ at $0$, which is $v$. Now, multiplying gives us $2av$, as desired.

More precisely, what does this mean? This means, that $f(x') \approx f(x) + 2a\bar{v}|v|$, where $\bar v$ is the unit vector in the direction $x'-x$ is, and $|v|$ is the magnitude of $x'-x$.

Note that in our case, since $x,x'$ are all real numbers, $|v|$ is just $|x'-x|$, and $\bar v$ is $\pm 1$ depending upon whether $x'$ is to the left or the right of $x$.

Comment: Thanks for your help!! It is much more understandable for me right now

Comment: BTW, do you mean$$
\frac{df(\phi(t))}{dt} = \frac{d(f(\phi(t)))}{d\phi(t)} \frac{d\phi(t)}{dt}
$$

Comment: Yes I do, I will make the correction. Thank you.